# $response->getBody() is empty when testing Slim 3 routes with PHPUnit

Tags: php, slim

I use the following method to dispatch a Slim app's route in my PHPUnit tests:

```
protected function dispatch($path, $method='GET', $data=array())
{
    // Prepare a mock environment
    $env = Environment::mock(array(
        'REQUEST_URI' => $path,
        'REQUEST_METHOD' => $method,
    ));

    // Prepare request and response objects
    $uri = Uri::createFromEnvironment($env);
    $headers = Headers::createFromEnvironment($env);
    $cookies = [];
    $serverParams = $env->all();
    $body = new RequestBody();

    // create request, and set params
    $req = new Request($method, $uri, $headers, $cookies, $serverParams, $body);
    if (!empty($data))
        $req = $req->withParsedBody($data);

    $res = new Response();

    $this->headers = $headers;
    $this->request = $req;
    $this->response = call_user_func_array($this->app, array($req, $res));
}
```

For example:

```
public function testGetProducts()
{
    $this->dispatch('/products');

    $this->assertEquals(200, $this->response->getStatusCode());
}
```

However, as much as things like the status code and header are in the response, `(string) $response->getBody()` is empty so I cannot check for the presence of elements in the HTML. When I run the same route in the browser, I get the expected HTML output. Also, if I `echo $response->getBody(); exit;` and then view the output in the browser, I see HTML body. Is there any reason, with my implementation, I'm not seeing this in the my tests? (in the CLI, so different environment I guess)

Answer (score 1):

`$response->getBody()` will be empty as you've set up the parsed body. It's easier to put it into the `RequestBody` as a string in the same way as it would be set if it came in over the wire.

i.e something like this:

```
protected function dispatch($path, $method='GET', $data=array())
{
    // Prepare a mock environment
    $env = Environment::mock(array(
        'REQUEST_URI' => $path,
        'REQUEST_METHOD' => $method,
        'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
    ));

    // Prepare request and response objects
    $uri = Uri::createFromEnvironment($env);
    $headers = Headers::createFromEnvironment($env);
    $cookies = [];
    $serverParams = $env->all();
    $body = new RequestBody();
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $body->write(json_encode($data));
    }

    // create request, and set params
    $req = new Request($method, $uri, $headers, $cookies, $serverParams, $body);
    $res = new Response();

    $this->headers = $headers;
    $this->request = $req;
    $this->response = call_user_func_array($this->app, array($req, $res));
}
```